# How to create 1 forest plot for multi- and univariable (factor variables) Cox regression results

Tags: r, ggplot2, cox-regression, r-forestplot

I have browsed multiple similar questions here but always get stuck by different problems, probably because I am not good at R.
I need to create a forest plot with several variables made of various levels of factors that includes its uni- and multivariable HR estimates. The HR lines of each factor level should be on top of each other and grouped by the main variables.

I have tried the code below, but I would like to have the main variable names on the left of the plot, next or above each factor (Not on the right as from the code). Also, the factor levels need to be ordered specifically, for example: General childhood condition levels: Poor, Fair, Good, Very good, Excellent. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Here is a snippet of my dataset & ggplot script:

```
df <- data.frame(
  label = c("Low", "Middle", "High", "Good", "Fair", "Poor", "Very  good", "Excellent", "Low", "Middle", "High", "Good", "Fair", "Poor", "Very good", "Excellent"), 
  var_label = c("Education", "Education", "Education", "General health", "General health", "General health", "General health", "General health", "Education", "Education", "Education", "General health", "General health", "General health", "General health", "General health"),
  reference = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"), 
  estimate = c(1.00, 1.34, 1.67, 1.00, 0.82, 1.11, 0.85, 1.48, 1.00, 2.67, 3.49, 0.83, 1.00, 0.95, 1.34),
  std.error = c(NA, 0.16, 0.20, NA, 0.16, 0.24, 0.18, 0.24, NA, 0.14, 0.18, NA, 0.16, 0.23, 0.18, 0.24),
  conf.low = c(NA, 0.95, 1.10, NA, 0.60, 0.69, 0.60, 0.92, NA, 2.01, 2.45, NA, 0.61, 0.63, 0.66, 0.83),
  conf.high = c(NA, 1.87, 2.52, NA, 1.11, 1.80, 1.21, 2.39, NA, 3.55, 4.98, NA, 1.13, 1.58, 1.35, 2.16),
  p.value = c(NA, 0.09, 0.02, NA, 0.20, 0.67, 0.38, 0.11, NA, 0.00, 0.00, NA, 0.24, 1.00, 0.76, 0.23),
  model = c("m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u")
)
```

```
dotCOLS = c("#a6d8f0","#f9b282")   
barCOLS = c("#008fd5","#de6b35")
forest <- ggplot(df, aes(x = estimate, xmax= conf.high, xmin = conf.low, y = label, color = model, fill = model)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 18, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_linerange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), size = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, size = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 1) +
  facet_grid(var_label~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=barCOLS)+
  scale_color_manual(values=dotCOLS)+
  scale_y_discrete(name="Variable groups") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Hazard ratio", limits = c(0, 5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = var_label), x = Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 1, vjust = 4.5, check_overlap = TRUE, color = "darkgreen") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"),
        axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(size = 1), 
        strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())
```

And here is a picture of the result:
[image: forestplot with multi- and univariable HR estimates]

Comment: go through this : https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggforest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want the labels on the left use `x=-Inf` in `geom_text`. Also, instead of shifting via vjust you could IMHO simply use `vjust=1` to align at the top. Additionally use `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` to prevent the labels from being clipped off and make some room for the labels by adding some `margin` to the y axis text. Finally, if you want your labels in a specific order than convert to a factor with the levels set in your desired order.

Note: I fixed your data which had only 15 values for the `estimate` variable while all other columns had a length of 16. Additionally I removed the `geom_hline` which IMHO is not necessary (at least for your example data).

```r
dotCOLS <- c("#a6d8f0", "#f9b282")
barCOLS <- c("#008fd5", "#de6b35")

library(ggplot2)

df$label <- factor(df$label, levels = c("Low", "Middle", "High", "Good", "Fair", "Poor", "Very  good", 
                                        "Excellent", "Very good"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = estimate, xmax = conf.high, xmin = conf.low, y = label, color = model, fill = model)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 18, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_linerange(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), size = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, size = 1) +
  #geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 1) +
  facet_grid(var_label ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = barCOLS) +
  scale_color_manual(values = dotCOLS) +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "Variable groups") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Hazard ratio", limits = c(0, 5)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = var_label), x = -Inf, y = Inf, hjust = 1, vjust = 1, check_overlap = TRUE, color = "darkgreen") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"),
    axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(size = 1),
    axis.text.y.left =  element_text(margin = margin(l = 20, unit = "pt")),
    strip.background = element_blank(), 
    strip.text = element_blank()
  )
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
#> Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(
  label = c("Low", "Middle", "High", "Good", "Fair", "Poor", "Very  good", "Excellent", "Low", "Middle", "High", "Good", "Fair", "Poor", "Very good", "Excellent"),
  var_label = c("Education", "Education", "Education", "General health", "General health", "General health", "General health", "General health", "Education", "Education", "Education", "General health", "General health", "General health", "General health", "General health"),
  reference = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE"),
  estimate = c(1.00, 1.34, 1.67, 1.00, 0.82, 1.11, 0.85, 1.48, 1.00, 2.67, 3.49, 0.83, 1.00, 0.95, 1.34, 1),
  std.error = c(NA, 0.16, 0.20, NA, 0.16, 0.24, 0.18, 0.24, NA, 0.14, 0.18, NA, 0.16, 0.23, 0.18, 0.24),
  conf.low = c(NA, 0.95, 1.10, NA, 0.60, 0.69, 0.60, 0.92, NA, 2.01, 2.45, NA, 0.61, 0.63, 0.66, 0.83),
  conf.high = c(NA, 1.87, 2.52, NA, 1.11, 1.80, 1.21, 2.39, NA, 3.55, 4.98, NA, 1.13, 1.58, 1.35, 2.16),
  p.value = c(NA, 0.09, 0.02, NA, 0.20, 0.67, 0.38, 0.11, NA, 0.00, 0.00, NA, 0.24, 1.00, 0.76, 0.23),
  model = c("m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "m", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u")
)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much! I do have a couple of follow-up issues. The original variable name is rather long, i.e. General childhood health, but this got cut-off on the left side. Could this margin limit be changed or long names be automatically broken into two lines to fit the space? Secondly, I would like to add a row with HR(95% CI) between the variable names and the y-axis, any suggestion on how to include that in the plot code? Again, I appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Well, these are a lot of questions. (: The easiest option would be to increase the left margin of the axis text which is already included in my code. For your other questions I would suggest to ask a (or two) new questions as these are not easy to fix, e.g. for a line breaks one option would be to add the category name as an helper obsevation to your dataset. This way it will be added to the axis texts automatically. No fiddling with the magins, you could have line breaks and the styling of the labels could be achieve via ggtext.

Comment: I see, then I will look into the second issue further before posting another question. For the text, I tried setting the left margin to 40 and 60, also reduced the x.axis scale to 0.5, but unfortunately the text is still cut-off. It might be best to just shorten the text anyway. Thank you again!